# Disable event of Inherited UserControl

Tags: c#, events

(Hi, all)

I have create a new user control inherit from tabcontrol, and override few events.

When I switch from one tabpage to another, the following event are fired in sequence:

```
1) OnDeselecting(TabControlCancelEventArgs e)
```

```
2) OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
```

```
3) OnMouseClick(MouseEventArgs e)
```

```
4) OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
```

How could I temporally disable 2) and 3) when 1) is fired?

Your help will be greatly appreciated!

PS:

I do need all of these events, and currently I am using a bool variable to do the dirty job.

.net 3.5+
VS2008+
Win7 64

Comment: Why you need this? Looks like a wrong way of a problem solving

Comment: I want to close a tabpage by click on customized area on the tab. And without lose focus on the current visited tabpage, if I close other tabpages.

Comment: A bool variable is the canonical solution, it is fine.  Just keep in mind that OnDeselecting is not only fired by mouse clicks, make sure it still works properly when you use left/right arrow and Ctrl+Tab.

Comment: Thanks,sll, Hans Passant and Steve, I will stick with the bool solution for a while.

Comment: To: Hans Passant, thanks, I will disable those function keys, and here is the link, hopefully it will help others as well. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/zh/winforms/thread/4b20fde3-118a-409a-94b9-65189944e9dc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in your OnDeselecting Event

```
try
{
    tab.MouseDown -= new MouseEventHandler(this.YourMouseDownEvent);
    tab.MouseClick -= new MouseEventHandler(this.YourMouseClickEvent);
    ..... // your code here.....
}
finally
{
    tab.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(this.YourMouseDownEvent);
    tab.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(this.YourMouseClickEvent);
}
```

Comment: Hi,Steve, I try your code, the event is not disable. So I will still use my original approach.Thanks for your reply.